# MySQL not using index for BETWEEN query. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, percona

I've tried different variations of this query but I just can't get it to use the timestamp index. What am I doing wrong?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

---

```
MariaDB [alienvault]> explain extended SELECT * FROM alienvault_siem.acid_event WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN '2012-10-09 11:20:17' AND '2012-10-10 03:20:17');
+------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | acid_event | ALL  | timestamp     | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4481579 |    50.00 | Using where |
+------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acid_event` (
  (...)
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  (...)
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  (...)
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  (...)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Software: Percona Server

Software version: 5.5.27-28.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 28.1

Comment: How many rows does the query return?

Answer (score 3):

Could be caused by:
 - index is not selective enough and mysql thinks full scan will by faster
 - mysql has bad index statistics

You can check output of "SHOW INDEX FROM alienvault_siem.acid_event;"
You can also try to force index use (but it might be bad in case if fullscan is faster):

```
SELECT * FROM alienvault_siem.acid_event FORCE INDEX (`timestamp`) WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN '2012-10-09 11:20:17' AND '2012-10-10 03:20:17');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you provided the date literals as strings.

If you use the `str_to_date()` function as in

```
WHERE timestamp 
  BETWEEN str_to_date('2012-10-09 11:20:17','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
      AND str_to_date('2012-10-10 03:20:17','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

then MySQL will be able to use the index.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(

MariaDB [alienvault]> explain extended SELECT * FROM alienvault_siem.acid_event WHERE timestamp BETWEEN str_to_date('2012-10-09 11:20:17','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND str_to_date('2012-10-10 03:20:17','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');

|    1 | SIMPLE      | acid_event | ALL  | timestamp     | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 6072587 |    50.00 | Using where |

1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Comment: That's odd. If I do "explain extended SELECT * FROM alienvault_siem.acid_event WHERE timestamp = str_to_date('2012-10-09 11:20:17','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');", the index is used but if I do "explain extended SELECT * FROM alienvault_siem.acid_event WHERE timestamp >= str_to_date('2012-10-09 11:20:17','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');", even tho "timestamp" is listed in possible_keys, no index are used and all rows are scanned (using where).

Comment: You should probably post this on a MySQL forum. You may be running into a bug.